# formula to map between two sequences

Tags: math, sequences

Given the 3 sequences below, I would like to be able to map seqN to seq0. seq1 maps to seq0 and seq2 to seq1 by:

```
seqN(i) = (seqN-1(i)*7)%27
```

For example,

```
seq1(i) = (seq0(i)*7)%27

seq0    0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20  21  22  23  24  25  26  27

seq1    0   7   14  21  1   8   15  22  2   9   16  23  3   10  17  24  4   11  18  25  5   12  19  26  6   13  20  27

seq2    0   22  17  12  7   2   24  19  14  9   4   26  21  16  11  6   1   23  18  13  8   3   25  20  15  10  5   27
```

Now, one way to do this will be to apply the function recursively. But that is not an option for me (this needs to be implemented in hardware). Nor can I save the values of the last sequence to calculate the value of the current sequence - I don't have space for it.

Is there a way to map seqN to seq0 using a mathematical equation (not recursive functions)?

Comment: Nitpick - your sequence should go from 0 to 26 instead of 27 (27 % 27 == 0)

Comment: This sounds like you should be using a LUT instead.

Comment: Thanks Dan, Ignacio.
Ignacio, I don't have space for the LUT...

Answer (score 0):

Apart from what @Nitpick pointed out (27 % 27 = 0, so you have either to stop at 26 or use 28 instead), you should simply use a power:

seq<sub>N</sub>(i) = ( seq<sub>0</sub>(i) * 7<sup>N</sup> ) % 27

Or:

seq<sub>N</sub>(i) = ( seq<sub>N-1</sub>(i) * 7 ) % 27 = ( seq<sub>N-2</sub>(i) * 7<sup>2</sup> ) % 27 = ... = ( seq<sub>N-N</sub>(i) * 7<sup>N</sup> ) % 27

Comment: Thanks Bob! This works. But the 'right' thing to do is to use %28 since I wouldn't like to look for that special case where LHS of the % operator is 27, to fill the output with 27 as well (instead of 0). How does the equation change then?

Comment: One answer would be: seqN(i) = ( seq0(i) * 7^N + x) % 28, where x increments by 1 every four i's. But this doesn't work for seq(2)

Comment: @AzemPasha are you sure that the sequences are the ones you posted? Is there any chance for the recurrence relation to be seqN(i) = (seqN-1(i)*7)%28? Does the sequences have only 28 elements or more? Because if you have only those elements and you are sure of the numbers, the best way is to set the 28th element to 27 and calculate the others.

Comment: The sequences are correct, yes. There can be more elements but in this case, there are 28.
I need to work with a different dataset to make sure that will work with the num_data - 1 in the RHS of the % OP.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this helps, but the transition of some `seq_N(i) -> seq_/{N+/-1}(i)` is completely determined by the following set of cycles:

```
List(0)
List(1, 7, 22, 19, 25, 13, 10, 16, 4)
List(2, 14, 17, 11, 23, 26, 20, 5, 8)
List(3, 21, 12)
List(6, 15, 24)
List(9)
List(18)
```

such that `0 -> 0`, `1 -> 7 -> 22 -> 19 -> 25 -> ...`, etc.

Based on these cycles you could take a number's position and translate it by `N % length_of_cycle` (just handling cycle wrapping) and get the original number.

I found these cycles with the following code(written in Scala) :

```
val m = (0 to 26).map(x => (x, x * 7 % 27)).toMap

var cycles = (0 to 26).map(x => {
    var x_i = x
    val oot = scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer(x)
    while (m(x_i) != x)
    {
        x_i = m(x_i)
        oot.append(x_i)
    }
    oot.toList
})

var filteredCycles = cycles.toArray

for (i <- (1 to 26))
{
    val cycle = filteredCycles(i)
    for (j <- (1 until cycle.size))
    {
        filteredCycles(cycle(j)) = List[Int]()
    }
}

val uniqueCycles = filteredCycles.filter(_.size != 0)
```